# Excel return cell without duplicates

Tags: excel, if-statement, duplicates, concatenation, lookup

I have a column that uses the `LOOKUP` function to pull a list of names from a separate sheet within the same workbook. The list of names is concatenated using an `IF` function - the list is in a single cell; names are separated by commas; and some names repeat.

Is there a function that can be applied or some other excel magic that can return this list of names without duplicates?

e.g. I have a table of company names in one column and account managers in another column - the `LOOKUP` function pulls the list of all account managers associated with that company into one cell with names separated by commas. For example, currently, the account managers shown for "Google" (A2) are "Bob, Joe, Bob, Tom, Bob" (B2), but I would like for it to only show "Bob, Joe, Tom".

EDIT:

Each row details a specific sale.

Column A: Company (a single company can appear multiple times)

Column B: Account Manager (a single name can be associated with multiple Companies)

Column C: concatenates Account Managers into single line using formula `=IF(A2=A1,C1&", " & B2,B2)`

Every time new data is added, the entire sheet is sorted A-Z by Company. The goal of the concatenation is to have ALL Account Managers associated with that particular company in one cell so that that cell can be referenced in the table mentioned above, which appears on a separate sheet in this workbook; however, if that AM has made multiple sales for the same company, the formula still adds it to the final list, which can result in a list of "Bob, Joe, Bob, Tom, Bob" when I want to see "Bob, Joe, Tom".

The formula I use in the table to reference this list of AMs for each company is `=LOOKUP(A5,'7.1.16 data'!A:A,'7.1.16 data'!C:C)`

Comment: Please post an image.

Comment: what is the lookup and If formulas you are using?  It may be easier to stop the duplicates there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a SEARCH query in your IF statement:

```
=IF(A2=A1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2, C1)), C1, C1 &", " & B2),B2)
```

---

Regards

Cg